# How to stop Google from indexing or following anything inside a directory

Tags: php, wordpress, iframe, googlebot, nofollow

I have WordPress site and an iframe, which src is 'http://my-website.com/www.downloadedwebsite.com/index.html'. I had to download iframed website, because I'm modifying a few things in it and that requires same-origin. There are no backlinks to this URL - just single iframe src'ing to it, however, I see Google has indexed it (bad!).

How can I stop Google from indexing or following anything that is inside "http://my-website.com/www.downloadedwebsite.com/" directory?

Answer (score 0):

Google surely still not do is associating the framed content with the parent page. So your pagerank will not be influenced.But you can stop it from robots.txt.

in robots.txt disallow the path.

User-Agent: *

Disallow: /folder-name/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using robots.txt?

For a single page you can also use a meta tag

```
<head>
<meta name="robots" content="noindex">
</head>
```